# CSS Multiple IDs - Not all of them are working

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with multiple IDs with CSS not working.

This is my FULL code:

```html
<html>
        <head>
         <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    
            <style>
    
    
    /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
    .topnav {
        background-color:RGB(12,30,60);
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT"
    }
    
    /* Change the color of links on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }
    
    /* Add a color to the active/current link */
    .topnav a.active {
        background-color: RGB(255,192,0);
        color: white;
    }
    
    
    
    
    #header
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
        margin-top: 30px;
    }​
    
    #testa
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
        margin-top: 30px;
    }​
    
    
    
     
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="classification.html">Classification</a>
        <a class="active" href="october.html">Data Visualisation</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="header">
            <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
            <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
    </div>
    
    <div id="testa">
            <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
            <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Whilst the 'header' css works, the 'testa' does not, despite them being EXACTLY the same (except the ID names). I have tried MULTIPLE IDs and it still causing the same issue.

Interestingly enough, if I put the 'testa' css before the 'header' css, neither of them will work.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It works fine for me !

Comment: It seems there is **Nothing** wrong with the code......

Comment: You cannot put html elements in the head like that - the head is for meta, style and scripts  tags and the main title tag

Comment: Oh! I will move the logo into the body! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a weird char behind you {} brackets for #header and #testa.

please try the style below:

```
<style>
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color:RGB(12,30,60);
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT"
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: RGB(255,192,0);
    color: white;
}




#header
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#testa
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
    margin-top: 30px;
}
</style>
```

> \u200b

That char is breaking your css.

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Yes someone else also spotted that. Not sure how that got there! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have hidden character, delete them and it will work

[image]

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />

        <style>


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color:RGB(12,30,60);
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT"
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: RGB(255,192,0);
    color: white;
}




#header
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#testa
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
    margin-top: 30px;
}




</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="classification.html">Classification</a>
    <a class="active" href="october.html">Data Visualisation</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="header">
        <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
        <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
</div>

<div id="testa">
        <!-- *** Section 1 *** --->
        <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I thought I was going mad. So what exactly was my issue?

Comment: @ScoutEU, I have left a comment in your previous question

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code on CodePen, and I found a strange character after the declaration of #header (see pen : https://codepen.io/sachaandre/pen/bYxXGx)

```
#header
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
  margin-top: 30px;
} /* <-- there is a small plain circle hidden here */
#testa
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

It's a small plain circle, if you take it away the code works fine ;) (I don't know why its invisible here

Between, if you have the exact same CSS definition, why you don't put it in a class ?

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. Oh it isnt the same HTML/CSS in my code... I made it the same for testing purposes as I could not work out why it wasnt working! :)

Answer (score 0):

@ScoutEU I think you might have forgotten to add one more - in while you are commenting. Check this I have made some change might be helpfull for you.

```html
<html>
        <head>
         <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
    
            <style>
    
    
    /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
    .topnav {
        background-color:RGB(12,30,60);
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT"
    }
    
    /* Change the color of links on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }
    
    /* Add a color to the active/current link */
    .topnav a.active {
        background-color: RGB(255,192,0);
        color: white;
    }
    
    
    
    
    #header
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    #testa
    {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT";
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    
    
    
     
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="classification.html">Classification</a>
        <a class="active" href="october.html">Data Visualisation</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="header">
            <!-- *** Section 1 *** ---->
            <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
    </div>
    
    <div id="testa">
            <!-- *** Section 1 *** ---->
            <h3>Time series of applications to 'Research Grants (Open Call)' for this Financial Year<br> and the previous three with 'Bollinger Bands'.</h3><br>
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @ScoutEU if you are happy with my answer please accept the answer and up vote me.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the problem.